# How to list all variables and procedures a Tcl package exports?

Tags: tcl

I'd like to know what procedures a packages provides or exports in order to use it, one way is look for package documentation but maybe it's not accessible.

So is there any way to make introspection to discover what the package provides?

I've tried info but theres no subcommand for querying packages, I've tried also package but there's no subcommand to list contents or exported symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do that. You can get the Tcl files loaded by `source` during a package's initialisation using [`package files`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/package.html#M5) (with Tcl 8.7/9.0 onwards; 9.0b1 available as I write this) but that doesn't tell you about the contents of those. Or about any shared libraries `load`ed, or what they defined. Nor does it track anything that was set up to autoload later (not that that's a mechanism I'd particularly recommend for modern code). And it doesn't track if a package does tricky things with another interpreter during initialisation... but I don't know of any that does.

Comment: ok, so maybe an issue for a future TIP...

Comment: Yes. Sounds like something to interest Jan Nijtmans in. Unfortunately, there isn't currently any call at all to track general command creation (or general variable creation either); new machinery required...